# Groovy Installation with MacPort fails on Mac OS X (10.7.5)

Tags: macos, ros-groovy, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to install ROS Groovy on my Mac BookAir and it goes fine until I have to compile. I've followed all the steps and, after the cmake step, when I'm building ROS base I got the next error:

```
$ make
[  0%] Built target cpp_common
Linking CXX shared library ../devel/lib/librospack.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt() in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::path::m_erase_redundant_separator(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::path& boost::filesystem3::path::append<std::string>(std::string const&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::path::m_append_separator_if_needed()", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::path& boost::filesystem3::path::append<std::string>(std::string const&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem3::path const&)", referenced from:
      rospack::Rosstackage::exports_dry_package(rospack::Stackage*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) in rospack.cpp.o
      boost::filesystem3::operator/(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::filesystem3::path const&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::current_path() in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp::~dir_itr_imp() in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::create_directory(boost::filesystem3::path const&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem3::path const&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::increment() in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::detail::status(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem3::is_directory(boost::filesystem3::path const&) in rospack.cpp.o
      boost::filesystem3::is_regular_file(boost::filesystem3::path const&) in rospack.cpp.o
      boost::filesystem3::exists(boost::filesystem3::path const&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::path::parent_path() const", referenced from:
      rospack::Rosstackage::inStackage(std::string&) in rospack.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem3::path::filename() const", referenced from:
      rospack::Rosstackage::isStackage(std::string const&) in rospack.cpp.o
      rospack::Rosstackage::crawlDetail(std::string const&, bool, int, bool, std::vector<rospack::DirectoryCrawlRecord*, std::allocator<rospack::DirectoryCrawlRecord*> >&, boost::unordered_set<std::string, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >&) in rospack.cpp.o
      rospack::Rosstackage::inStackage(std::string&) in rospack.cpp.o
      rospack::Rosstackage::addStackage(std::string const&) in rospack.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [devel/lib/librospack.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that is something related to rospack and boost libraries. Any idea about how to solve it?? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51309/groovy-installation-with-macport-fails-on-mac-os-x-(10.7.5)/) by [Álvaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3882/%C3%A1lvaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are missing boost, make sure it is installed.

I have not looked at the MacPorts instructions recently, I am not sure who is maintaining those.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0